# Nginx error upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:

Tags: php, nginx

I am using NGINX as a load balancer on my server which just proxies the request to application servers according to their weight.

Since this morning I have started getting this error on browser

> 502 Bad Gateway

and checking the NGINX error logs it says

> upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:

On the application server (Apache + PHP) page called invokes a PayPal setexpresscheckout request through php-sdk.

Sometimes it works (refreshing page multiple times) without throwing 502, so the problem is intermittent.

I have tried following options:

1. Increasing proxy buffer size in NGINX conf.
2. Turning buffering option off
3. Increasing proxy read timeout up to 5s

None of the above worked.  Can anyone please point me in right direction?

Comment: Check logfiles of the upstream server (not nginx).

Comment: Yeah, I did checked the upstream server logs, but unfortunately there was nothing specific about the error. But then I restarted the Apache on both my upstream servers and it worked. So in a way your suggestion worked for me as I was just playing with the load balancer nginx only. Thanks for taking your time to reply :-)

Comment: Where could one find said upstream server logs? :) P.S. I know where my apache logs are and where the PHP logs are but not quite sure about nginx if the upstream logs are inside an nginx log.

Comment: Oh, is that like the `proxy_error_log` file?

Comment: In my case the upstream servers were the servers running Apache+php,  so I checked the Apache logs.